# Upgrade spring boot to version 2.2.6, nginx return error 400

Tags: spring-boot, nginx-config

After we upgrade  version spring boot to version 2.2.6, nginx service can not connect to microservice. I have spent lot of time read log from nginx, change port ... But the reason is proxy of spring boot.

So we have add the config as below:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

it works for me.

Comment: Do you get a 400 from nginx or from the Spring Boot service?

Comment: Upgrade from which version to which version?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli from spring boot service.

Comment: @M.Deinum, from 2.0.x to 2.2.6

Comment: What do you see in the log? Please post the stacktrace

Comment: I strongly suggest you read the documentation about upgrading from 2.0 to 2.1 and 2.2. There is  lot of information in the upgrade/changes documentation about changes etc.